# Can a Power Automate flow update my custom column to display just the folder name where the document is uploaded inclusively for subfolders?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

Can a Power Automate flow update my custom column in SharePoint to display just the folder name where the document is uploaded inclusively for subfolders?

I want it to show just the folder name where it is stored in and not the path or something. I want it to happen just when a document is uploaded.

I'd like to accomplish this to ensure that when searching for a document using tags or any other method, you can readily determine the folder in which each document is stored.

I'm aware that there's a manual method to achieve this within SharePoint itself, but it requires manual intervention each time a folder is created. Therefore, I'm seeking automation for this process.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the path on the forward slash and then get the second last item. That will give you folder name.

For example, if you have a path like this `/Folder Test/Folder 1/Folder11/SampleDocument009.pdf`, you could create a variable to hold the split parts of the path. The expression in the screen capture is `split(outputs('Get_file_metadata_using_path')?['body/Path'],'/')`.

[image: Initialize variable action]

You can the get the folder name using an expression like this, `variables('SplitPath')[sub(length(variables('SplitPath')),2)]`.

[image: Test result]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what did you use before the "Get file metadata using path"? And where did you use the `variables('SplitPath')[sub(length(variables('SplitPath')),2)]`? I am pretty new to Power Automate so I am trying to understand how to do this :)

Comment: Oh and what kind of file path did you use inside the "Get file metadata using path"?